# How to split files with numeric names?

Tags: linux, split, words

I'm trying to split text file into files of 1024 lines, so I ran `split` with the `-d` switch:

```
split -d -l 300 ./list.lst
```

I get some weird names: they start with `x` and the file names jump from `x89` to `x9000`. I want the files to be named like that:

```
1.lst
2.lst
3.lst
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with the GNU Coreutils version of `split`, you can do it as follows:

```
split -l300 --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=1 --additional-suffix=".lst"  file ""
```

Note the use of `""` to specify an empty prefix (the `xa` part of the default filename) and the use of `--numeric-suffixes` in place of `-d` (which always starts from 0).

Note also that this assumes that the file to be split contains no more than 9 x 300 lines - otherwise `split` will complain that `output file suffixes exhausted`

Ex.

```
$ split -l300 --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=1 --additional-suffix=".lst" --verbose file ""
creating file '1.lst'
creating file '2.lst'
creating file '3.lst'
creating file '4.lst'
```

Comment: With `--suffix-length=1` it is only possible to create 9 parts (1-9). The user is creating more than 89 parts (because he reports filenames as x9000). So, length should be at least 3 (or more).